# Provisioning - AWS_CDK vs Troposphere vs Stacker

Tags: continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment, aws-cdk, troposphere

Troposphere is a python project for AWS provisioning. This is a mature project.

AWS CDK is still in developer preview.

`cdk diff` does help on **ease of state maintenance** before `cdk deploy`. Am not sure, how troposphere helps us on state maintenance? except generating a cloudformation template...

From [AWSEvent talk](https://youtu.be/Lh-kVC2r2AU), it is mentioned that, abstractions are not built-in for using Troposphere

where as

AWS CDK has good abstractions.

CDK enables CI/CD, [easily](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/308), where-as Troposphere needs extra automation to upload CF templates

We need to take a decision on picking one, to provision our infrastructure on AWS

---

From the aspect of state maintenance, software best practice, code maintenance & supported resource types, CI/CD(end-to-end automation) for provisioning,

What are the advantages of AWS_CDK vs Troposphere vs Stacker? being open to any programming language..

Comment: FYI that CDK is no longer in developer preview. It's now GA (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloud-development-kit-cdk-typescript-and-python-are-now-generally-available/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

troposphere is part of what CDK does, a more apt comparison would be stacker (https://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which uses troposphere -- I'm a maintainer of both) vs CDK.  Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: How do you compare Stacker with AWS CDK? What features does Stacker add on top of troposphere?

Comment: stacker is the orchestration layer around  troposphere, much in the same way that CDK orchestrates the building of cloudformation stacks.  stacker has a ton of features and has been around for a while.  I haven't taken a close look at CDK recently, so won't be able to give a great apples to apples comparison, but I'd say take a look at stacker for the orchestration type tasks.

Comment: I just took a look at the video - stacker provides an open source library of abstractions around a lot of troposphere objects.  You can see those at: https://github.com/cloudtools/stacker_blueprints

Comment: When you say Orchestration logic, are you referring to main features? https://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#main-features

Comment: Yep! You define all the stacks you want in your infrastructure, stacker builds it and makes sure it keeps up to date based on any changes.  This is a bit old, but the basics remain the same:

https://www.whaletech.co/2017/02/28/Tooling-around-with-CloudFormation-helpers.html

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000872/does-cdk-perform-orchestration-apart-from-provisioning

Comment: @phobologic a lot of time passed - is your answer still valid? How to decide to switch?