# Does CDK perform orchestration ? apart from provisioning

Tags: ansible, aws-cloudformation, provisioning, orchestration, aws-cdk

We used CloudFormation/Terraform for provisioning resources in AWS.

Provisioning is about creating a new state

or

transforming one state to another.

for example: a state is a machine installed with apache web x.y

---

We used ansible tool to orchestrate provisioning

Automation is to define task that can be executed automatically.

Automation may be used on the single system. Orchestration takes the automation and coordinates the process between multiple systems. Usually because one system may be dependent on another system before it can accomplish its task. You cannot have orchestration without automation.

So, Orchestration is about resolving dependencies

Ansible playbooks help in orchestration

---

But AWS CDK looks more programmer friendly for provisioning

Below commands

```
aws cdk init

aws cdk synth

aws cdk deploy
```

are take care of provisioning in AWS

---

For orchestration, Does AWS CDK also take care of resolving dependencies? amidst provisioning

Comment: Stacker also helps in orchestration logic: https://stacker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#main-features   But we are preferring a single tool for both provisioning and orchestration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set dependencies between stacks within a CDK application that will orchestrate how it would build the stacks similar to how other CloudFormation orchestration tools would, e.g. Stacker. Dependencies can be explicit or implicit via abstractions within CDK.

An example would be in the cross-stack reference examples for Python in the CDK examples repository: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python/cross-stack-resources/native-objects

In the above example, there's an implicit dependency set between the Infrastructure and the Application stack where the Application stack depends on the Lambda being created by the Infrastructure stack to build the its own API Gateway.

An explicit example would be using the `add_dependency(construct)` method, e.g.

```py
shared_stack = SharedStack(
    app,
    "SharedStack",
    stack_name='-'.join( [ app.node.try_get_context('app_name'), 'shared', app.node.try_get_context('env') ] ),
    **splat
)

lambda_stack = LambdaStack(
    app,
    "LambdaStack",
    stack_name='-'.join( [ app.node.try_get_context('app_name'), 'lambda', app.node.try_get_context('env') ] ),
    **splat
)

lambda_stack.add_dependency(shared_stack)
```

Answer (score 0):

CDK is just an abstraction on Cloudformation. Cloudformation does provide orchestration to some degree. However it would be helpfull if you would specify what you exactly mean by orchestration. 
What do you really mean bij 'resolving dependencies'. It's a bit ambiguous in this context. CDK is modular and in a way has dependencies with resolving as well. But I think you are referring to something else.